# Celery and Django on production machine

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

**/opt/fubar/fubar/celery.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fubar.settings')

app = Celery('fubar')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**/opt/fubar/fubar/**init**.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celeryworker.conf**

```
[program:fubar-celery]
command=/opt/fubar/env/bin/celery worker -A fubar --loglevel=INFO
directory=/opt/fubar
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/fubar/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/fubar/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

`$ service rabbitmq-server status`

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-07-26 06:19:47 UTC; 19h ago
 Main PID: 21884 (rabbitmq-server)
    Tasks: 92 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─21884 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
           ├─21905 /bin/sh /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
           ├─22073 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.2/bin/epmd -daemon
           ├─22185 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.2/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -zdbbl 32000 -K true -B i
           ├─22299 erl_child_setup 65536
           ├─22372 inet_gethost 4
           └─22373 inet_gethost 4
```

`$ celery worker -A fubar --loglevel=INFO` on localhost returns

```
[tasks]
  . fubar.celery.debug_task
  . apps.raptor.tasks.launchraptor
  . apps.raptor.tasks.nolaunch
```

while I see no tasks in the log file in production

Apache error log shows:

```sh
mod_wsgi (pid=26854): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/fubar/fubar.wsgi'.
...
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'apps.raptor.tasks.launchraptor'
```

1. I installed supervisor with `pip install supervisor` to get v4.2.0
2. What can I run to test whether things are configured properly?
3. Why is celery worker started with supervisor not finding the tasks that show up when run as celery worker.

Answer (score 0):

0. I got rid of RabbitMQ and moved to redis. I had more success installing/configuring redis. Doesn't answer the question asked.
1. Observation was that supervisor installed with `pip install supervisor` doesn't work and does when done via `apt install supervisor`. I don't know why.
2. `tail -f /var/log/celery/fubar/worker.log` is the best way to see what's going on with the worker.
3. `celery inspect ...` also works for a snapshot of whats happening
4. I had to change command= in the conf.d/fubar*.conf files to point to a shell script which worked better than calling celery from the conf file itself. Also, shell scripts must be owned by the user=value and set to +x.